# Assign a function with custom parameters without calling the funcion

Tags: javascript

I've a function A which accepts at run-time another function B as parameter and calls it. The problem is the function B needs some parameters, but I don't know how to pass the function B, with parameters, to the the function A.

Example:

```
function callerFunction(c)
{
alert("The caller is calling the function!");
c(c.arguments);
};
var a = "hello";

function thisOne(d)
{
    d = "I changed my way";
    alert(d);
};
callerFunction( /* I NEED TO PASS THE 'thisOne' with the parameter/variable 'a' here, and then call it inside 'callerFunction' */);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass a closure:

```
callerFunction(function() { thisOne(a); });
```

And call it as `c()`, not `c(c.arguments)`.

Note that this anonymous function will reference the `a` variable, not the value `a` had at that moment.  So if `callerFunction()` was to store this function object and call it later, if you changed the value in `a` between passing the anonymous function and the time it is called, the value of `a` from the perspective of the anonymous function would have changed:

```
var a = 1;

var fn = function() { console.log(a); };

fn(); // Logs 1

a = 2;
fn(); // Logs 2
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but is there another way? I don't like to crate another function which calls the function I need; a way wothout this new 'middle' function.

Comment: @sigur This is the most straightforward way to accomplish this in a language with closure and first-class functions. You will find that this is a very common pattern.